How to programmatically check if Kafka Broker is up and running in C using rdkafka
I'm trying to consume messages from a Kafka topic. I need to check if connection is established before I start consuming messages because I need to invoke a conn_callback when connect to broker.
I need to perform some action for the connection to get established. But I want to check the connection establishment without doing a consume or poll operation.
Now I use rd_kafka_offsets_for_times to check the connection, if it returns no errors it means connect successfully.The issue is the consumer didn't recieve the message which was published 500ms later than rd_kafka_offsets_for_times return success but the seconde message can be recieve by the consumer, it seems the consumer connection to broker is later than rd_kafka_offsets_for_times return success. I still have no idea about the root cause after a few days investigate.Has anyone know the same issue?
In another way I want to find the funtion can instead rd_kafka_offsets_for_times to check the status of the broker,does anyone know?
find the function that can check if connection is established exactly.
